# 'when' statement without classname

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to use the 'when' statement, without putting it on a class, like this:

**Attempt 1:**

```
@responsive: false;
when (@responsive = false) {
  @screen-xs:                                   0px;
  @screen-sm:                                   0px;
  @screen-md:                                   0px;
  @screen-lg:                                   0px;
}
```

Somehow this doesn't work. How do i make this work properly?

---

**Attempt 2:** This doesn't work either:

```
@responsive:                                false;
@screen-xs:                                 (0px) when (@responsive = false);
@screen-sm:                                 (0px) when (@responsive = false);
@screen-md:                                 (0px) when (@responsive = false);
@screen-lg:                                 (0px) when (@responsive = false);
```

---

**Attempt 3:** This doesn't work either:

```
@responsive:                                false;
.container when ( @responsive = true ) {
  @screen-xs:                                   480px;
  @screen-sm:                                   768px;
  @screen-md:                                   992px;
  @screen-lg:                                   1200px;
}
.container when ( @responsive = false ) {
  @screen-xs:                                   0px;
  @screen-sm:                                   0px;
  @screen-md:                                   0px;
 @screen-lg:                                    0px;
}
```

**Attempt 4:** This doesn't work either:

```
@responsive:                                false;
.res {
  @screen-xs:                                   480px;
  @screen-sm:                                   768px;
  @screen-md:                                   992px;
  @screen-lg:                                   1200px;
};
& when (@responsive = false) {
  .res {
    @screen-xs:                                 0px !important;
    @screen-sm:                                 0px !important;
    @screen-md:                                 0px !important;
    @screen-lg:                                 0px !important;
  };
}
.res();
```

---

**Attempt 5:** This doesn't work either:

```
@responsive:                                false;
@screen-xs-breakpoint:                      480px;
@screen-sm-breakpoint:                      768px;
@screen-md-breakpoint:                      992px;
@screen-lg-breakpoint:                      1200px;
& when (@responsive = false) {
    @screen-xs-breakpoint:                  0px;
    @screen-sm-breakpoint:                  0px;
    @screen-md-breakpoint:                  0px;
    @screen-lg-breakpoint:                  0px;
}
@screen-xs:                                 @screen-xs-breakpoint;
@screen-sm:                                 @screen-sm-breakpoint;
@screen-md:                                 @screen-md-breakpoint;
@screen-lg:                                 @screen-lg-breakpoint;
```

Comment: Or is this just not possible with LESS?

Comment: What is the bigger picture? Where are you trying to use the variables or what are you doing with it?

Comment: i want to say in my less file: if @responsive is false: change variable1 variable2 variable3. This way i can disable responsiveness easy for my boostrap template.

Comment: i can change for example my body background (body{ background: red}) with: & when (@responsive = false) { body: {background: red;}}. But when i try to change variables, they won't seem to override.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate but I couldn't find an exact matching thread. I will answer because you have tried a lot of methods and I want to explain why each doesn't work. I will also suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attempt 1:** The below code wouldn't work because guards need to be attached to a selector. If there is no specific selector you could use `&` as an unnamed namespace.

```
@responsive: false;

when (@responsive = false) {
  @screen-xs: 0px;
}
```

Without any selector, Less wouldn't be able to compile it and you would end up getting the below error:

> Parse error: Unrecognised input

---

**Attempt 2:** This would also fail for the same reason as stated above. Guards can be used only with selectors and not with variables.

```
@responsive: false;
@screen-xs: (0px) when (@responsive = false);
```

---

**Attempt 3:** This should have worked but I can only assume that you had not invoked the mixin anywhere.

```
@responsive: true;
.container when ( @responsive = true ) {
    @screen-xs: 480px;
}
.container when ( @responsive = false ) {
    @screen-xs: 0px;
}
```

When you don't invoke the mixin, the variables that are set within the mixin are never actually set and the compiler would give the below error:

> Name error: variable @screen-xs is undefined

It would have worked fine if you had called the mixin like in the below snippet:

```
&{
  .container();
  #div1{
    width: @screen-xs;
  }
}
```

---

**Attempt 4:** This again would not work because you are never actually calling the mixin that is within the unnamed namespace.

```
@responsive: true;
.res {
    @screen-xs: 480px;
}
& when (@responsive = false) {
  .res {
    @screen-xs: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

---

**Suggested Solution:** The below is the approach that I would suggest for your case.

```
@background: white;
@screen-xs: 480px;

.responsive(@responsive) when (@responsive = true){
  @background: blue;
  @screen-xs: 240px;
}
.responsive(@responsive) when (@responsive = false){
  @background: red;
  @screen-xs: 120px;
}

&{ /* unnamed namespace is required because the mixin that sets the value should be called within the same scope */
  .responsive(@responsive);
  #div1{
    background: @background;
  }
  #div2{
    width: @screen-xs;
  }
}

@responsive: true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of everything i did. This way i'm understanding is better. But it isn't possible to not add it do a id or class? I just want bootstrap to suck it up and do it's job with it, but add the values on 'width:' or 'background:', if you know what i mean?

Comment: Sry, pushing "ENTER" everytime. (doesn't work here ;)).

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't work on problems outside of SO. If you are not completely satisfied with my answer, please wait and see if you get a better one (or) if you have a new question, you can create a separate thread.

Comment: No problem, i thought id would be more easy for you to see the complete work to see what i'm trying to accomplish. And then after that, we could upgrade the answer on SO. But you've been very helpful, so i can't ask for more.

Comment: @jananne Btw., how do you change the value of the `@responsive` variable? Manually or via compiler options?

Comment: @jananne See my answer below then (though it actually should fit regardless of that).

Answer (score 2):

For the particular Bootstrap problem (unleashed in comments of the answer by @Harry (that cover the solutions to be always recommended when possible)), here are a few tricks that could fit depending on how you actually compile your CSS.

First of all you can just change `@responsive` from boolean to something that allows to change variables directly, e.g.:

```
@responsive: 0; // 1 for responsive and 0 otherwise
@screen-xs:  (480px * @responsive);
@screen-sm:  (768px * @responsive);
@screen-md:  (992px * @responsive);
@screen-lg: (1200px * @responsive);
```

No conditions - no tears ;)

---

Obviously it's not always possible to use above simplification, so
here're other solutions (they look more complicated than above suggestion but it's typical to use those to fight non-modular configuration-via-bunch-of-global-variables pattern used in certain frameworks):

First of all since you obviously don't compile those Bootstrap themes simultaneously, it's actually not even necessary to have all this stuff to appear in the same file, i.e. the most straight-forward solution would be just to create two independent main files to compile, e.g.:

```
// my-responsive-bootstrap.less:

@import "bootstrap.less";
@import "whatever-else-you-need-to-import.less";

@screen-xs: 480px;
@screen-sm: 768px;
@screen-md: 992px;
@screen-lg: 1200px;
```

and

```
// my-non-responsive-bootstrap.less:

@import "bootstrap.less";
@import "whatever-else-you-need-to-import.less";

@screen-xs: 0px;
@screen-sm: 0px;
@screen-md: 0px;
@screen-lg: 0px;
```

That's it (the point is that you already have and apply your condition at the moment you compile, so it does not make real sense to duplicate the same condition in the code at all).

Sure often we still need a similar code to appear nearby for more easy maintenance, so it's possible to combine above two files into one again:

```
.responsive(true); // true or false

.responsive(true) {
    @import (multiple) "bootstrap.less";
    // @import (multiple) "whatever-else-you-need-to-import.less";
    // ...

    @screen-xs:  480px;
    @screen-sm:  768px;
    @screen-md:  992px;
    @screen-lg: 1200px;
}

.responsive(false) {
    @import (multiple) "bootstrap.less";
    // @import (multiple) "whatever-else-you-need-to-import.less";
    // ...

    @screen-xs: 0px;
    @screen-sm: 0px;
    @screen-md: 0px;
    @screen-lg: 0px;
}
```

Voilà. (further it's possible to simplify it more by combining same imports into another mixin (or another file) to be reused in `.responsive()` etc. etc.)

Comment: Just in case, to answer "the root" question ("why I can't conditionally *redefine* a variable") the answer is "Less is a declarative language and because of that (or more specifically because of Lazy-Evaluation behaviour typical for common declarative languages), any conditional construction that allows to override previously defined variable opens a door to not solvable and potentially undetectable self-recursion" (see [#2072](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2072) for specific examples).

Comment: You.. (both) are the best! Thanks!